# KeyError: 'Close', I think I deleted a key for my dictionary! Algo Trading

Tags: python, dictionary, trading, keyerror

When I run the first two functions, CARG and Volatility, they work fine! When I run Sharpe, it runs into problems! I think I deleted a key in my dictionary somehow, it refers back to my CAGR function and point to the second line in there, saying KeyError: 'Close'. The return error info is at the very bottom

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


tickers = ["AAPL","AMC","SPY","BBBY"]

ohlcv_data = {}

for ticker in tickers:

temp = yf.download(ticker, period="7mo", interval="1d")
temp.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)
ohlcv_data[ticker] = temp

def CAGR(DF):
    
    df = DF.copy()
    df["return"] = DF["Close"].pct_change()
    df["cum_return"] = (1+df["return"]).cumprod()
    n = len(df)/252 
    CAGR = (df["cum_return"][-1])**(1/n) - 1
    
    return CAGR

for ticker in ohlcv_data:
    print("GAGR for {} = {}".format(ticker, CAGR(ohlcv_data[ticker])))


def Volatility(DF):

    df = DF.copy()
    df["return"] = DF["Close"].pct_change()
    vol = df["return"].std() * np.sqrt(252)

    return vol

for ticker in ohlcv_data:
    print("Volatility of {} = {}".format(ticker, Volatility(ohlcv_data[ticker])))


def Sharpe(DF, rf=0.03):

    df = DF.copy()
    return (CAGR(df)- rf)/Volatility(df)

for ticker in ohlcv_data:
    print("Sharpe for {} = {}".format(ticker, Sharpe(ohlcv_data, 0.03)))

def Sortino(DF, rf=0.03):

    df= DF.copy()
    df["return"] = df["Close"].pct_change()
    neg_return = np.where(df["return"]>0,0,df["return"])
    neg_vol = pd.Series(neg_return[neg_return!=0]).std()

    return (CAGR(df)- rf)/neg_vol

for ticker in ohlcv_data:
    print("Sortino for {} = {}".format(ticker, Sortino(ohlcv_data, 0.03)))




File "c:\users\cryst\onedrive\documents\algotradingcode\untitled11.py", line 56, in <module>
print("Sharpe for {} = {}".format(ticker, Sharpe(ohlcv_data, 0.03)))

File "c:\users\cryst\onedrive\documents\algotradingcode\untitled11.py", line 53, in Sharpe
return (CAGR(df)- rf)/Volatility(df)

File "c:\users\cryst\onedrive\documents\algotradingcode\untitled11.py", line 26, in CAGR
df["return"] = DF["Close"].pct_change()

KeyError: 'Close'
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: all your code is wrong you create dictionary `{name: df}` but later you send this dictionary to function and you expect `dataframe` - you have to send `ohlcv_data[ticker]` instead of `ohlcv_data`

Answer (score 0):

I see the same mistake when you run `Sharpe()` and `Sortino()`

You send `ohlcv_data` but you have to send `ohlcv_data[ticker]`

Funny is you have it correctly when you run `CAGR()` and `Volatility()`

```
    Sharpe(ohlcv_data[ticker], 0.03)
    
    Sortino(ohlcv_data[ticker], 0.03)

    CAGR(ohlcv_data[ticker])

    Volatility(ohlcv_data[ticker])
```

---

Eventually you should use `.items()` to make it more readable

```
for ticker, data in ohlcv_data.items():
    result = Sharpe(data, 0.03)
    # result = Sortino(data, 0.03)
    # result = CAGR(data)
    # result = Volatility(data)
```

---

Full working code with:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def CAGR(DF):
    
    df = DF.copy()
    
    df["return"] = df["Close"].pct_change()
    df["cum_return"] = (1+df["return"]).cumprod()
    n = len(df)/252 
    CAGR = (df["cum_return"][-1])**(1/n) - 1
    
    return CAGR

def Volatility(DF):

    df = DF.copy()
    
    df["return"] = df["Close"].pct_change()
    vol = df["return"].std() * np.sqrt(252)

    return vol

def Sharpe(DF, rf=0.03):

    df = DF.copy()
    
    return (CAGR(df)- rf)/Volatility(df)

def Sortino(DF, rf=0.03):

    df = DF.copy()
    
    df["return"] = df["Close"].pct_change()
    neg_return = np.where(df["return"]>0,0,df["return"])
    neg_vol = pd.Series(neg_return[neg_return!=0]).std()

    return (CAGR(df)- rf)/neg_vol

# --- main ---

tickers = ["AAPL","AMC","SPY","BBBY"]

ohlcv_data = {}

for ticker in tickers:
    data = yf.download(ticker, period="7mo", interval="1d")
    data.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)
    ohlcv_data[ticker] = data

for ticker, data in ohlcv_data.items():
    result = CAGR(data)
    print(f"GAGR for {ticker} = {result}")

for ticker, data in ohlcv_data.items():
    result = Volatility(data)
    print(f"Volatility of {ticker} = {result}")

for ticker, data in ohlcv_data.items():
    result = Sharpe(data, 0.03)
    print(f"Sharpe for {ticker} = {result}")

for ticker, data in ohlcv_data.items():
    result = Sortino(data, 0.03)
    print(f"Sortino for {ticker} = {result}")
```

Result:

```
GAGR for AAPL = 0.11355213703707379
GAGR for AMC = -0.5829820257957625
GAGR for SPY = -0.05423536518372174
GAGR for BBBY = -0.4389927079102395
Volatility of AAPL = 0.3471946896720913
Volatility of AMC = 1.3227122428032356
Volatility of SPY = 0.24545485475277398
Volatility of BBBY = 1.5613839405009773
Sharpe for AAPL = 0.24064923664582766
Sharpe for AMC = -0.4634281032257359
Sharpe for SPY = -0.3431806849718452
Sharpe for BBBY = -0.30036988068403025
Sortino for AAPL = 5.847323456223871
Sortino for AMC = -11.478142948375877
Sortino for SPY = -8.132265719790464
Sortino for BBBY = -7.791889967534535
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)